# Git repush everything after setting different config

Tags: git, newline

I'm developing across Windows and Linux machines. I realized that with a git config of `core.autocrlf = true`, some files had their CRLFs from Windows converted to LFs in Linux.

So on my Windows, in a text file I would see:

```
sometextCRLF
moreCRLF
hahahaCRLF
CRLF
moreCRLF
CRLF
```

While on Linux:

```
sometextLF
moreLF
hahahaLF
LF
moreLF
LF
```

Is there any way after I run

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

to force push everything so that my CRLFs aren't lost? (I can't push anything now since I don't have any changes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`core.autocrlf` has no effect on push, only on checkout. If you want to change existing working copies, you need to checkout them. If you want to change files in the repository you need to change and commit them manually and then push the new commits as usual.

Comment: Oh god, I was hoping there was an easier way, there's like 30 files. Scripting to the rescue!